# Loading data in background in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm trying to do certain operations like creating a table and inserting 720 rows at initial launch of the application which takes some time, so I decided to run it in background. Please see the code below,

MainActivity.java

```
DatabaseHandler dbhandler = new DatabaseHandler(this);
this.progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "Please wait...",
            "Downloading Passengers Information...", true, false);

new DownloadTask().execute();


private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(String... args) {

        for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++) {
                value = jedis.hget("passengerInfo",
                        String.valueOf(i + (char) (asciiA) + j)); //this will get the data from hash table passengerInfo created in Redis
                if (value != null) {
                    addSeat = String.valueOf(i + (char) (asciiA) + j);
                    paxInfo = value.split(",");
                    passName = paxInfo[0];
                    passAge = Integer.parseInt(paxInfo[1]);
                    passGender = Integer.parseInt(paxInfo[2]);
                    passFoodPref = paxInfo[3];

                    dbhandler.addPassengerInfo(new PassengerInfo(addSeat,
                            passName, passAge, passGender, passFoodPref));
                }

                else {
                    addSeat = String.valueOf(i + (char) (asciiA) + j);
                    passName = "NA";
                    passAge = 0;
                    passGender = -1;
                    passFoodPref = "NA";

                    dbhandler.addPassengerInfo(new PassengerInfo(addSeat,
                            passName, passAge, passGender, passFoodPref));
                }

            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
        // Pass the result data back to the main activity
        MainActivity.this.data = result;

        if (MainActivity.this.progressDialog != null) {
            MainActivity.this.progressDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run this it show the following error in logcat,

```
01-23 21:29:06.206: E/AndroidRuntime(704): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
01-23 21:29:06.206: E/AndroidRuntime(704): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
```

Please help !

FYI: Entire Logcat

```
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742): Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:134)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.connect(BinaryClient.java:69)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.sendCommand(Connection.java:79)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.BinaryClient.hget(BinaryClient.java:212)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.Client.hget(Client.java:138)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.Jedis.hget(Jedis.java:680)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.jedisconnectiontest.com.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:118)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.jedisconnectiontest.com.MainActivity$DownloadTask.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  ... 4 more
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742): Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.platform.OSNetworkSystem.connect(Native Method)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at dalvik.system.BlockGuard$WrappedNetworkSystem.connect(BlockGuard.java:357)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:204)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at org.apache.harmony.luni.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:437)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:983)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:129)
01-23 21:53:15.807: E/AndroidRuntime(742):  ... 13 more
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742): Activity android.jedisconnectiontest.com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40523ac8 that was originally added here
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity android.jedisconnectiontest.com.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@40523ac8 that was originally added here
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.view.ViewRoot.(ViewRoot.java:258)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:107)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ProgressDialog.show(ProgressDialog.java:95)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.jedisconnectiontest.com.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:56)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
01-23 21:53:17.737: E/WindowManager(742):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You probably wanna post your entire logcat error output.

Comment: Once `doInBackground()` finishes execution (after it's fixed), the next problem is that `data` will always be null since you only `return null` from `doInBackground()`

Comment: `Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out` Seems to me `.hget(...)` doesn't only retrieve data from a hashmap/hashtable but rather fetches them from some kind of server

Comment: @A--C But I don't want to return any data so i gave null. If not null then what I should return?

Comment: @SrujanSimha It's fine that you return null, but then why are you assigning it to a variable? `MainActivity.this.data = result;` will always be null. So if you don't want the result, just don't assign to `MainActivity.this.data`. Also consider using `Void` (capital V) instead of `Object` - it makes it clearer that your code won't be using the value.

Comment: @Tedil Before trying this I tried getting only one value from hashmap and it worked fine. May be the problem is not with that, but I really don't understand why it is showing Connection timeout.

Comment: @A--C I tried as you suggested, but still facing the same issue.

Comment: @SrujanSimha note that I wrote "**the next problem**". Your current problem is the timeout, your next problem is the null assignment.

Comment: I agre with Tedil. hget is probably trying to fetch some data but has no connection or is misconfigured. Try to read some documentation on that method usage

Comment: @A--C, Tedil, snapix - Yeah ! you ppl are correct. The issue is with connection. I should punch on my face, bcoz I gave wrong IP address for connecting to redis !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Connection timed out
```

This error means that the server did not answer between the given TimeOut value (normal about 10 seconds), is your server down? Or did you misspelled the server url?

Comment: I did not see that, quick answer!